# reading a specific bucket file from bucketed table created by parent pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF (v1) pipeline P1 with a single activity of type HDInsightHive. It's a monthly pipeline. The associated query produces a partitioned and bucketed external table (3 buckets).

So when we look at the external data produced by it, this is what it looks like:-

```
  ../basefolder/2018/07/000000_0
  ../basefolder/2018/07/000000_1
  ../basefolder/2018/07/000000_2
```

So these are the 3 files associated with the 3 buckets within the monthly partition (in the example it is July 2018). So because of bucketing , for every month there will be these 3 files.

Now I want to create 3 child pipelines again of HDInsightHive type (but it could be different type as well, that's not imp) which will depend on P1 i.e. wait for P1 to finish processing for a given month slice. Say the 3 pipelines are C1,C2,C3. But, though all 3 should wait for P1 to finish processing for a given month, when the processing of C1,C2,C3 starts for that month, they should consume 000000_0, 000000_1 and 000000_2 respectively. If I just create 3 pipelines like that making P1 as parent, ideally they will start consuming all the 3 files.

I need a way so that I can dictate C1, C2 & C3 that they should only read file with specific names.

The issue is that the output dataset of P1 will be the common input dataset for C1,C2,C3. So I can't hardcode file name as part of this common input dataset.

Here is the diagram of what I am trying to achieve:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution that comes to my mind is that for the parent pipeline P1, even though it is single activity, I will declare 3 output datasets D1,D2,D3 with different output file names. And then when I declare 3 child pipelines C1,C2,C3 , I will point these to D1,D2,D3. This is just a vague idea, I will have to do a POC around it.

**Update:** it works using the method I described.

Answer (score 0):

If you could switch to ADF V2, I think this would be easy to achieve with [execute pipeline activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) and ADF v2 [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions).